# How can I use numpy.timedelta to add(or subtract) 1 month?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timedelta

I'm trying to decrement a date to 1 month. I mean to get the same date 1 month earlier.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

pd.to_datetime(201905, format='%Y%m') - np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

I expected to get the 1st day of previous month like

> Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00')

But the output is

> Timestamp('2019-03-31 13:30:54')

The problem seems to be the same when I'm trying to add a month.

Code

```
pd.to_datetime(201905, format='%Y%m') + np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

Returns

> Timestamp('2019-05-31 10:29:06')

instead of

> Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00')

How can I solve the issue?

My final goal is to take date in the integer format YYYYmm (like 201905) then add (or subtract) any number of months and return new date in the same format (integer, YYYYmm). Maybe it can be done easily with another packages?

Comment: A month is not a consistent unit of measure, I expect that to be the reason.

Comment: Months can be 28, 29, 30, or 31 days long, depending.  It does not make sense to say "exactly one month".

Comment: @dspencer yes, you are right. Timedelta in months can not be represented via days or hours. But in SQL it works fine. I can't belive, nothing is already created for python.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, saying this I mean "to get the same date but N month earlier". Including correct jumps through years. Like 201801 - 1month = 201712.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timedelta of one month is the length of a year divided by 12, so it is `'average'` month unit:

```
a = pd.to_datetime(201905, format='%Y%m') - np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
print (a)
2019-03-31 13:30:54
```

If want subtract 1 month use [`offsets.DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
b = pd.to_datetime(201905, format='%Y%m') - pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)    
print (b)
2019-04-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I was looking for.